# How imaging and recovery is done in Yocto

Tags: linux, deployment, embedded-linux, yocto, imaging

I have developed an Yocto Image for my hardware with all the changes..

How can I achieve imaging on Yocto.. I mean how can I capture the partitions on Yocto and flash it on the other similar devices.

What are ready made solutions available for this deployment setup in Yocto. I am using swupdate layer for software updates

Comment: You can create image for your device (sd or emmc) using `wic` plugin in yocto. Deployment here you mean flashing into the sd/emmc automatically by Yocto?

Comment: yes.. Currently we manually boot into the live image, and then select "Install" using GRUB menu and then type the hard disk("sda"), and some "Y" to requests. There should not be all those

Comment: We want to deploy everything over PXE. New units will have their disks blank.. So, is there any way by PXE Boot the flashing happens automatically

Comment: I am not sure. But you may be interested in http://etherboot.org/wiki/index.php etherboot. Poky integration https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Poky_NFS_Root